# CPAssembler error: Web control file is not located inside your website

Tags: content-delivery

I'm getting this error when trying to get content using the `componentPresentationAssembler.GetContent()` method:

> CPAssembler error: Web control file is not located inside your website.

The path of the DCP folder in storage.config is correct and the  folder is inside same website root directory.

Comment: I have had this error in past in .NET due to this path setting being case-sensitive. Can you confirm the path is correct, including case? (copy/pasting the path from Windows Explorer was how I solved it)

Comment: I assume from the fact that you are using a storage config that this is Tridion 2011 or 2013.  Can you tag your question with a release version please?  It is also worth noting that the path to the DCP folder (in the storage config file) is case sensitive.  Unless there is a strong business case not too, I would tend to implement these using RELs as they are far more scalable.  More information is on Will's Tridion Developer post [here](http://goo.gl/RRcNE)

Comment: Nuno you r right path was wrong i put the correct path now i m getting this error CPAssembler error: WAIPage object not initialized. Make sure to use the ComponentPresentationAssembler constructor that accepts a WAIPage i m intializing CPAssembler  like this ComponentPresentationAssembler cpAssembler = new ComponentPresentationAssembler(pageURI);

Comment: when i use intialization like this ComponentPresentationAssembler componentPresentationAssembler = new ComponentPresentationAssembler("tcm:0-0-0", this.Page); i got my previous error again CPAssembler error: Web control file is not located inside your website.

Answer (score 6):

Problem solved. The issue was in the cd_storage_config file where I had an item `typeMapping` set to use the wrong `itemExtension`. The specific issue was with the entry:

```
<Item typeMapping="ComponentPresentation" itemExtension=".ascx" storageId="defaultDataFile"/>`
```

In my case `itemExtension` was `.asp` by mistake. I changed it to `.ascx` and everything works.

Comment: Can you tell us what the cause was so that it may guide others that come across this question please?

Comment: Agreed. Will change my downvote once the answer is updated.

Comment: sorry nuno for late replay i was out of town actual problem was here in this line <Item typeMapping="ComponentPresentation" itemExtension=".ascx" storageId="defaultDataFile"/> in my condition itemExtension was ".asp" by mistake i change it to ".ascx" and everything works

Comment: Abdul, I edited your answer to include the contents of your comment.